# How to change date format of published post

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I want to change date formate of published post in WordPress, Currently date format is  `<?php the_time('m.d.y'); ?></div>` i.e "1.20.2018"

I want to change it to "January 20, 2018".

How to achieve this format in php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the function "the_time" is built of the "date" PHP function. If that's the case, you should really check the [documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) on how to create your own date format.

In the case you've specified, the function would be

```
the_time("F d, y");
```